# JavaScript is it okay to use eval here

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, eval

```
function ...(...){
     function queen(){...}
     function rook(){...}
}
```

I want to call a function based on a variable name

I.e. for a chess game and checking the piece movements.

```
if (piece === "rook") rook();
```

If the value is "queen" it calls queen()

Is it okay to use

```
eval(piece+"()");
```

Are there any alternatives to this without doing writing a switch statement or an if chain for this kind of thing.

Comment: Nope. Use an object.

Comment: Yep. Why not use a wrapper for all your pieces such as `var pieces = {'queen' = {...}, 'rook' = {...}};`, then you can easily say, `pieces[piece]();`.

Comment: @DaveChen—I think you meant `var pieces = {queen: function(){...}, rook: function(){...}, ...}`.

Comment: @RobG Yep, I'm getting all my languages mixed up at the moment :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common work-around for solving this without `eval()` is to put the functions as properties on an object and then use object/property nomenclature to execute the desired function.

```
var pieceOperations = {
    queen: function() {...},
    rook: function() {...}
};

var piece = "rook";
pieceOperations[piece]();    // executes pieceOperations.rook()
```

Javascript does not offer a way to solve your original issue of executing local functions via a string in a variable without using `eval()` because it does not expose the local scope object that you can reference a property of (though that object exists internally, it is kept internal).  So, if you want to access by name, just put the resource as a property on an object rather than as a local variable and you can then access it via the `obj[prop]` syntax.

---

As for using `eval()`, if you are 100% sure you know the source of the `piece` variable and thus you know that you can never get some unanticipated code there, then it is safe to use `eval()`.  The safety of using `eval()` depends entirely upon the source of the string that you're passing to `eval()`.  That said, I prefer to just avoid `eval()` entirely and thus I don't have to wonder about the safety issue or a performance issue (`eval()` can be much slower).  I've always found another way to write the code that does not require `eval()` such as the above work-around.